# Django Login form Using AD

Tags: django, authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create an App which has a log in page where user should be authenticated using azure AD. Basically the App has a log in form where user puts his id and password from ad and django should check with ad and allow him in or not. Later on ofc would like to add permission depending on AD group.

So far I searched a lot on the internet and found nothing. Could you guys help with some example or link to documentation what I could use.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd like to suggest that you don't do that.
What you are asking for is ROPC flow: https://joonasw.net/view/ropc-grant-flow-in-azure-ad.

Usage of this flow is not recommended unless this is for migrating a legacy application (which is the original purpose of ROPC).
It also won't work if the user has MFA, an expired password etc.

There is usually no reason why you'd want to handle user passwords when using a federated identity provider.